# Can you connect to the blockchain and send dapp data without a wallet?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to be able to process dapp info outside of the dapp.

So usually you open the dapp site and connect your wallet. In my case I can then interact with the dapp to say buy crypto.

I have a dapp that requires you to press a button multiple time a day, I'd like to automate this so no user input is needed.

So I'd need to connect to the blockchain with no wallet then find out how the dapp sends data to the blockchain and send this data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this dapp developed by you? Was the contract deployed by your own wallet?

Comment: No, it is not possible. To modify the contract's state you have to send a transaction, and transaction are always signed.